# How to validate if karate.configure(SSL) for X509 certificate authentication is successful or not

Tags: karate

We are using karate.configure(SSL) for X509 certificate authentication. Working fine. We want to validate if SSL configure is completed successfully or not in feature file to proceed to next step. Is there anyway to validate?

How to handle if there is more than 1 keys in keystore.

The only information printed in console is below (for keystore file :test.jks).

key store key count for classpath:test.jks: 1 - if configuration is success
key store key count for classpath:test.jks: 0 - if configuration is not success

Please help. Let me know if more details required.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand exactly what you need, so here's what I suggest:

- go through this issue, it was very difficult to get SSL Cert support working: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/281
- follow the instructions here so that we are clear what exactly you are looking for: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
- if you can contribute a patch to Karate in addition to the above that would be ideal
- try using Karate's Java interop to validate the SSL cert yourself and integrate into your test manually

Comment: I managed to get what i wanted after referring the documents.